# Importing data into Django richtextfield is losing line breaks formatting

Tags: mysql, django, import, ckeditor

I'm transferring a lot of data into a django db.
One of the fields is richtextfield from  django-ckeditor

I will set the field through a script to some text like

```
content = "this is some text.\r\n\r\nthis is the next paragraph.\r\n\r\nthis is another paragraph."
```

But when I view this on my django site, or in the admin console, it will not have any line breaks and be all one paragraph.

Is there some way to keep the line break formatting when importing into a richtextfield?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the linebreaks filter when rendering your content in your template: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#linebreaks

It should be as simple as:

```
{{ content|linebreaks }}
```

Comment: Thanks that worked for the template, how do I fix it for the admin editing page?

Comment: Is it possible for you to just store it in the db with html tags? Before saving it to the db you could use the linebreaks util function (from django.utils.html import linebreaks).

Comment: Yes applying content = linebreaks(content) to the records before saving it solves both problems completely, without needing the line breaks filter in the template. Thanks